# $NP$, $P^{TFNP}$ and $P^{UP}$

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Is it possible

1. $NP\subseteq P^{TFNP}$ holds or
2. $NP\subseteq P^{UP}$ holds

without the polynomial hierarchy collapsing?

Is there problems in

3. one of each of the classes from $NP$, $P^{UP}$ and $P^{TFNP}$ but not in other two?
4. two of each pair of the classes from $NP$, $P^{UP}$ and $P^{TFNP}$ but not in last?

Comment: We [know](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=22196) $\mathbf{NP} \subseteq \mathbf{RP}^{\mathbf{PromiseUP}}$ (i.e., $\mathbf{NP}$ problems are reducible to promise problems in $\mathbf{UP}$ using Cook reductions with one-sided error). $\mathbf{NP} \subseteq \mathbf{P}^\mathbf{UP}$ would be rather surprising.

Comment: @dkaeae Ah that is correct.